# One liner to create HLS stream

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer, http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash

IIUC with HLS or DASH, I can create a manifest and serve the segments straight from my httpd, e.g. `python -m http.server`.

I have a UVC video feed coming in on /dev/video1 and I'm battling to create a simple m3u8 in either gstreamer or ffmpeg.

I got as far as:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! mpegtsmux ! hlssink max-files=5
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Video**

To list `video1` device capabilities:

`ffmpeg -f v4l2 -list_formats all -i /dev/video1`

2. **Audio** (ALSA example)

To list ALSA devices:

`arecord -L`

3. **HLS**

Use two inputs:

```
 ffmpeg -f alsa -i <alsa_device> -f v4l2 -i /dev/video1 [...] /path/to/docroot/playlist.m3u8
```

You can find the various HLS parameters in the [FFmpeg documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#hls-1).

Further reading:

[FFmpeg H.264 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264)

[FFmpeg Webcam Capture](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Webcam)

Comment: Thanks though this doesn't work for me: https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2015-April/026263.html

Comment: Did you set the encoding parameters? Please update your question with the exact command. Playlist size and how many segments it creates/how long it keeps them are different things. Use `hls_flags delete_segments` to delete the old segments.

Comment: My cmdline is in the log here: http://ix.io/icO linked from the ffmpeg post of my earlier comment. :}

Comment: Ah, that's it :) ? You are relying on the default values which may not be a good idea (like someone noticed it has trouble with at least the pixel format). Take a look at the H.264 Encoding guide in my answer.

Comment: Sad that default values don't work here for this typical target. :/

Comment: Long story short: **-pix_fmt yuv420p** was needed. `ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -pix_fmt yuv420p playlist.m3u8` is the full working line.

Answer (score 0):

I found the option `tune=zerolatency` was what I needed it from stalling. Still need to figure out how to bring in the audio too.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency ! mpegtsmux ! hlssink max-files=5
```

Sadly my Thinkpad X220 is overheating at > 96C.

Would be nice to get the ffmpeg version.

Comment: I added the ffmpeg version but you should update the original question to include the above information.